# how to access constructor properties from a setInterval on angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

It seems that i cant access the constructor properties from an setInterval and i need to get and to modify the properties . any help on how can i solve this ?

```
startit() {
    console.log(this.page,this.nrpages) //works
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log(this.currentPage,this.nrpages) // undefined undefined
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use arrow function

```
startit() {
  console.log(this.page,this.nrpages) //works
  setInterval(() => {
      console.log(this.currentPage,this.nrpages);
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

The key point here is that `this` points to the current execution context. So inside `setInterval` function `this` is not referring to your outer execution context. You can do something like:

```
startit() {
    console.log(this.page,this.nrpages) //works
    var thiObj = this;
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log(thisObj.currentPage,thisObj.nrpages) //works
```

Comment: i like more this answer .. more javascriper :)

Comment: @RusMine, I suggest you get used to (embrace) arrow functions -- i.e., Günter's answer.  Less code is usually better.  And, besides `setInterval` and `setTimeout`, arrow functions are also quite useful with promises and observables.