# The (this) keyword not working in angular

Tags: angular, this

I'm wondering why 'this' keyword is not working in some functions inside angular project. Here is a small demo of what I mean

In AppComponent.ts file, I called a service method using 'this' from ngOnInit life cycle hook. this works fine, but when I tried calling the same service method using the same keyword 'this' inside setInterval() method, I got an error. so I want to know why is 'this' working in some methods and does not work in other methods?

Here is AppComponent.ts file

```
import { ServerService } from './-server.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _server: ServerService){}

 ngOnInit(){
   // this works fine
   this._server.getUSSDTransactionStatus().subscribe(resp=>{ 
     console.log('resp: ', resp); // I got response
   });

  let interval = setInterval(async function(){
     // this is throwing error
     this._server.getUSSDTransactionStatus().subscribe(resp=>{
       console.log('resp: ', resp)
     });
   }, 5000);
 }
}
```

Here is my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServerService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getUSSDTransactionStatus(){
    return this._http.get('http://********');
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to access constructor properties from a setInterval on angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258003/how-to-access-constructor-properties-from-a-setinterval-on-angular2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that the callback function inside setInterval is in a different **lexical environment**.

In ES6+ functions can be defined using =>. This is so that the code within a function shares the same scope as the function.

```
setInterval(() => {
  this._server.getUSSDTransactionStatus().subscribe(resp=>{
       console.log('resp: ', resp)
     });
   }, 5000);
});
```

or else you can assign one variable to **this** before using, like

```
    const _self = this;
let interval = setInterval(async function(){
     // this wont throw error now
     _self._server.getUSSDTransactionStatus().subscribe(resp=>{
       console.log('resp: ', resp)
     });
   }, 5000);
 }
```